# Detecting number characters in printed text without OCR engine

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection

I'm looking for a method that will allow me to detect number characters (0123456789) in *printed* *text* *images* **without** the usage of OCR libraries (e.g. Tesseract). Additionally, no training or other type of pre-existing information is available, since the algorithm must work on many different fonts and languages out of the box, except if there is some kind of universal training we can do that will be font insensitive.

Comment: One possible solution would include manually extracting some feature vectors (i.e.,  Euler number, number of Connected Components, etc.) from your fonts, build a data set and use that with a simple classifier ( e.g., Knn-based classifier with a proper distance measure) to categorize each character in a known class.

Comment: I specifically can't have any training, as I said in the description. The algorithm has to work on document images that it has never seen before. It is acceptable to say that what I'm asking for is not possible, it's just that digit characters are so universal and almost the same in most fonts that I thought there would be an image based way to detect them.